# django channel issue during deployment

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, django-channels, uvicorn, asgi

I am using Django Channels and deployed with NGINX+Gunicorn+Uvicorn and following the tutorial from Digital Ocean (i.e. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-asgi-django-app-with-postgres-nginx-and-uvicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I don't see any issue when I tried to run the site @ [www.myproject.com:8000](http://www.myproject.com:8000) without NGINX with the following command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.asgi -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

However, when I deployed with NGINX it is ok for most of the site functionality except the chat function page which employ django channels.

Somehow the websocket failed to connect through as shown by the error from browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://myproject.com/ws/chat/ADVPKG/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

Checking on the error log in the server, I saw:

```
2022/01/06 08:13:02 [alert] 16624#16624: *8421 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.myproject.com, request: "GET /ws/chat/ADVPKG/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/ws/chat/ADVPKG/", host: "myproject.com"
```

Included below is my code:
asgi.py

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django
django.setup()

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": django_asgi_app,
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.myproject.com
                myproject.com
                ""
                1X.XXX.XX.XXX
                ;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/stochie;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Basically:

1. I am pretty sure the issue is the nginx configuration as without nginx every function work perfectly
2. I heavily suspect that the 'proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0;' might be wrong which according to one forum questionnaire is due to infinite loop as proxy pass point to itself. So far based on other forum questionnaires, I have try 'localhost', 'localhost:8000', http://django, http://uvicorn but is not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: have you solved this issue, I'm facing the same issue right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in you `asgi.py`

remove the routings from your `asgi.py` and put this code in your `asgi.py`

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

then create `routings.py` something like this below and put `myproject.routings.application` in your `settings.py`

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': OriginValidator(
        TokenAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter([
                url(r"^ws/courier/$", CourierConsumer.as_asgi()),
                url(r"^.*$", NoRouteFoundConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        ),
        ['*'],
    ),
})
```